# How does all this components work and communicate to each other?

Tags: asp.net, api, web-applications, dll, windows-services

I would like others to explain about Windows Service, API and CIM Framework(.dll) to me.

I'm an intern and very new to all this, I have tried researching about the issue I addressed below in net and also read through a few guide in my organization but can't understand much. It's confusing. 
Can anyone explain precisely in simple words, what does Windows Service, API and CIM Framework(.dll) do with a web application? I will be able to get an idea to begin creating web application using all this if I understand all of this first. Please advise. Thanks!

Comment: What is the context here?  Do you know what a Windows Service is?  What is the API you are talking about? CIMFramework.dll is a third party library. Why are you using this?

Comment: Windows Service is another application right? Correct me if I'm wrong. I need to use it to connect with a back-end database to check for the date of products, and if the date is today, then I will need to change its status in the back-end database from active to not active. Web app is just an UI to authenticate user and initiate the windows service, CIM Framework has the common functions that is widely used to call services from back-end database. We can either use CIM Framework or API right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A windows service is just an application that runs in the background inside Windows Operating Systems.  You can view what services you have running by either going to your COntrol Panel -> Administrative Tools -> Services.  These are just programs that you can write yourself. .NET provides an easy way to do this via a template you can choose when you create a new service. You can also control servics via the command line . There is a good article here on both methods: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-au/library/cc736564%28v=ws.10%29.aspx

You use Windows Services to perform automatic operations in the background where you don't need any human intervention into their program.  You can do what you want with one, you just need to ask yourself is this the best way to do this.

An API (Application Programming Interface) is just a way to communicate with another system. Today, this is often done via a RESTful service if it is over the internet.

I don't know what CIM is. You typically communicate with a backend database via an API of sorts. For SQL Server on Windows this is normally via .NET ADO or LINQ. Perhaps CIM does this into your database for you.